# How to set the entire path name into the variable in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on nodejs. I have to set my entire pathname into the variable.

I tried this to set the path name in to the variable

```js
var secretKey = path.basename("../Users/secretkey.pem");
```

when I console.log the variable I'll get only the filename `secretkey.pem` alone but not get the exact path that I mentioned.

How to Set the Exact path into the variable.

Comment: path.basename() is a function that returns only the filename portion of the path, so that part is correct. Do you want to het the absolute path? Otherwise why not just store the path as string? `var secretKey = "../Users/secretkey.pem";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Node documentation | Path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext):

> The path.basename() method returns the last portion of a path

which is exactly what you report as the output in your console.

Try the following:

```js
const file_name = path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'Users/secretkey.pem'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `resolve`. It Resolves the specified paths into an absolute path.

```
var fullpath = path.resolve("../Users/secretkey.pem");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and see if it helps ([link](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)):

```
var filename = path.resolve('../Users/secretkey.pem');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need the absolute path of the `secretkey`.

You can do something like this

```js
var filename = "secretkey.pem";
var fullpath = __dirname + "/Users/" + filename;
```